# Are there better ways to Select which IDs do not exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a better way to achieve this same result?

I have a list of IDs (not in a table). I need to find which of the IDs does not exist in a given table. I've been able to achieve the results I'm looking for by executing the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT InlineID
FROM (SELECT 11111 AS InlineID UNION ALL SELECT 22222 UNION ALL SELECT 33333) AS Ids
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable ON Ids.InlineID = MyTable.ID
WHERE MyTable.ID IS NULL;
```

While this works, it feels as though there ought to be a simpler way to achieve the same result, i.e. the repetitive UNION ALL statements look messy, especially when the list of IDs grows large. One other restriction is that I don't have rights to be able to create temp tables, so those types of solutions will not be possible.

Comment: Added tag to indicate SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT InlineID
FROM   (VALUES (11111),
               (22222),
               (33333)) T(InlineID)
EXCEPT
SELECT ID
FROM   MyTable
```

Comment: Works like a champ and reads a bit cleaner.Thanks, I think this is what I'll end up going with.

Comment: Huh! Never knew you could do that! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Martin Smith nice query just wanna ask why did you add `T(InlineID)` to the query?

Comment: @LoneWOLFs - The question is for SQL Server 2008 not MySQL. MySQL definitely doesn't support `EXCEPT` and not sure if it supports row constructors either. `T(InlineID)` defines an alias for the derived table and column defined by the `VALUES` clause.